# htaccess for links with ? and non numeric parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In .htaccess I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^name/body/test$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/new_name [L,R=301] #1 - OK
RewriteRule ^name-450$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/name450[L,R=301] #2 - OK

RewriteRule ^name.php?id=13&new_id=8$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301] #3 - NOT WORKING

RewriteRule ^data/others/aaa/all/bbb/all/ccc/750$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/new_data [L,R=301] #4 - NOT WORKING
RewriteRule ^data/others/aaa/1/bbb/2/ccc/750$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/new_data [L,R=301] #5 - OK

RewriteRule ^?num=123$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301] #6 - NOT WORKING
</IfModule>
```

Why 3, 4 and 6 not working? How can i make it?

Comment: You simply cannot test for get parameters inside the rewriting module. They are _not_ part of the URL!

Comment: @arkascha so how can I make redirects for these links?

Comment: You can't use `?` in a `RewriteRule`, you need to include a `RewriteCond` and inspect the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. More [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: @arco444 can you show me to my examples?

Comment: @arkascha: _“You simply cannot test for get parameters inside the rewriting module. They are not part of the URL!”_ – that’s wrong on multiple levels. Of course the query string is part of the URL – but `RewriteRule` only tests the _path_ component of the URL. And as was already said, the query string can be tested using a `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rules 3 and 6 would end up being as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=13&new_id=8
RewriteRule ^name.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^num=123$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [L,R=301]
```

Rule 4 looks fine to me so can only suggest you're not testing it properly.

Comment: Thanks, but this redirect me to http://mypage.com/?id=13&new_id=8 instead of http://mypage.com. This remove only "name.php"

Comment: Sure, see the update, just add an empty query string to strip the old one.